# Why does my 10.7 PCIe SSD card appear as an external, ejectable disk?

Tags: macos

I have just added some OWC Mercury Accelsior E2 SSD cards, which are PCIe. Within the Finder, these drives appear as external disks (traditional orange icon on the Desktop) and in the Finder sidebar, they appear with an eject icon next to them.

Why do these drives appear as external, ejectable disks? (And is there any way to get OS X 10.7 to treat these as 'regular' internal drives?)

Comment: Is this a hackentosh? If so, the topic has been covered here: http://www.tonymacx86.com/general-help/67495-internal-drive-showing-up-external.html

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/621106/how-do-i-make-a-external-drive-appear-as-an-internal-drive